# Xcode-generated iOS provisioning profiles not visible in Member Center

Tags: ios, xcode8, provisioning-profile

My Xcode-generated iOS provisioning profiles aren't showing up under 'Provisioning Profiles' in 'Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles' in the Member Center. I'm trying to find out if this is the expected behavior, or if it's an error of some sort.

It may be addressed in the documentation somewhere, but I haven't found it. I searched stackoverflow but didn't find any discussion of the issue. I've found mention of what sounds like the same issue on other forums, but haven't found any clear answers.

I have an individual paid developer account, and everything else seems to be working as expected.

My Xcode-generated profiles appear correctly in Xcode->Preferences->Accounts->View Details. If I delete a profile in Xcode (right-click, 'Move to Trash'), the profile remains in the list, but now has a 'Download' button next to it. If I click the 'Download' button the profile is restored. This suggests to me that the profile does in fact exist in my online account somewhere. But if that's the case, I don't understand why it's not displayed in Member Center.

Are Xcode-generated provisioning profiles supposed to be visible in Member Center? If not, why can they be downloaded after deletion in Xcode?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: I never resolved it. As I mentioned in a comment below, I've been away from Xcode for a bit and haven't looked at this using the latest version, so it may be that things work differently now.