# Does Xcode 10 no longer update automatic provisioning profiles in the member center?

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

Yesterday I logged into the apple dev member center and checked our Provisioning Profiles and they all are expired. However I did upload several apps/updates to the store the day before and Xcode shows valid profiles when I check the build settings.

Until last Xcode it used to be so that Xcode created "XC iOS: [App ID]" distribution profiles in the dev center and the new Xcode does no longer do that.

Is there any way to force/make Xcode refresh or update the profiles in the dev center?

There is a similar question but without answers
[Xcode-generated iOS provisioning profiles not visible in Member Center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41593579/xcode-generated-ios-provisioning-profiles-not-visible-in-member-center)